# Python 3: Transpose columns of Pandas Data Frame / "melt" data frame

Tags: python

I have a Pandas Data Frame like this:

```
    uid   category   count
0    1     comedy     5
1    1     drama      7
2    2     drama      4
3    3     other      10    
4    3     comedy     6
```

Except there are dozens of categories, millions of rows, and a few dozen other columns.

I want to turn that into something like this:

```
    id   cat_comedy   cat_drama    cat_other
0    1    5            7            0
1    2    0            4            0
2    3    6            0            10
```

I have no idea how to do this and am looking for tips/hints/full solutions. I don't really care about the row index.

Thanks.

Comment: No, not a mistake.

Comment: @CarlCervone suggested that your data set may have lines that have the same `id` and `category`, but a different count - is that correct, or would any combination of `id` and `category` be unique in your data?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're after (the operation is called a 'pivot'):

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame([
    {'id': 1, 'category': 'comedy', 'count': 5},
    {'id': 1, 'category': 'drama', 'count': 7},
    {'id': 2, 'category': 'drama', 'count': 4},
    {'id': 3, 'category': 'other', 'count': 10},
    {'id': 3, 'category': 'comedy', 'count': 6}
]).set_index('id')

result = df.pivot(columns=['category'])

print(result)
```

Result:

```
          count
category comedy drama other
id
1           5.0   7.0   NaN
2           NaN   4.0   NaN
3           6.0   NaN  10.0
```

In response to your comment, if you don't want the `id` as an index for the `df`, you can tell the operation to use it as the index for the pivot. You'll need `pivot_table` instead of `pivot` to achieve this, as it allows can handle duplicate values for one pivoted index/column pair.

And replacing the `NaN` with zeroes is also an option:

```
df = DataFrame([
    {'uid': 1, 'category': 'comedy', 'count': 5},
    {'uid': 1, 'category': 'drama', 'count': 7},
    {'uid': 2, 'category': 'drama', 'count': 4},
    {'uid': 3, 'category': 'other', 'count': 10},
    {'uid': 3, 'category': 'comedy', 'count': 6}
])

result = df.pivot_table(columns=['category'], index='uid', fill_value=0)

print(result)
```

However, note that the resulting table still has `uid` as its index. If that's not what you want, you can revert the resulting columns back to a normal one:

```
result = df.pivot_table(columns=['category'], index='uid', fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

The final result:

```
         uid  count
category     comedy drama other
0          1      5     7     0
1          2      0     4     0
2          3      6     0    10
```

Comment: Pretty close! Except the `id` field (I renamed it to `uid` in my original question in case that makes it clearer), should not be the index (I don't think). And the NaNs should be zeros

Comment: To replace `NaNs` with `0s`, call `df.fillna(0, inplace=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

The original answer from @Grismar (upvoted since he got it in first) is really close but doesn't quite work. Don't reset your index before the pivot call, and then do the following:

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(columns='category', index='uid', aggfunc=sum)
df2 = df2.fillna(0).reset_index()
```

df2 is now the dataframe you want. The `fillna` function replaces all the `NaNs` with `0s`.

Comment: Note that `df2` will still have `uid` as its index - a `.reset_index()` is required to revert it to a normal columns. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Good catch @grismar. Updated as well. Nice tag team.

Answer (score 1):

Complete solution using `pivot_table`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'uid': 1, 'category': 'comedy', 'count': 5},
    {'uid': 1, 'category': 'drama', 'count': 7},
    {'uid': 2, 'category': 'drama', 'count': 4},
    {'uid': 3, 'category': 'other', 'count': 10},
    {'uid': 3, 'category': 'comedy', 'count': 6}
])

df.pivot_table(
    columns='category', 
    index='uid', 
    aggfunc=sum, 
    fill_value=0
)
```

Comment: The `aggfunc` seems superfluous in this case?

Comment: The default `aggfunc` is `mean` so even though it would work for the dummy data shown here, it might not for other real datasets. For example, if you added another row like this: `{'uid': 3, 'category': 'comedy', 'count': 5}`